# Duration between intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of schedule that looks like this

```
Start Time 2016-6-20 7:30AM       End Time 2016-6-20 8:00AM
```

I want to create a query to calculate the duration between the intervals, it would work for 30 minutes but I don’t know how to create one for when it ends on 2:45 or 2:15. If I do date diff I would give me 30 minutes duration but for 2:15 or 2:45 it will not give me that

I want something to look like

```
7:30, Start time7:30, End Time 8:00AM, durwtion 30 minutes 
8:00, Start time 8:00, End time 8:15, duration  15 minutes
```

Comment: `end_time - start_time`? https://rextester.com/XHRPII51927

Comment: Microsoft DBMS 2018. End Time - Start Time wouldn't work because it's going to give me a total duration which is not what I basically need, I need duration between intervals.. For instance, Interval 1:30, Start Time 1:45, End Time 3:15, Goal 0:15, End-Start 1:30 and so on. Am I making sense now?

Comment: And how do you "know" what the interval value should be? You use 30 minutes in your description - is that an assumption on which you want to build a solution? What  happens when you have multiple rows which have a variety of start/end dates? And lastly, please post a script that contains DDL and sample data to avoid confusion.

Comment: I have a table that contains all intervals, starting at 12:00AM EST all the way up to 11:30PM EST, I made a join with the table I'm working with which contain Date_Time UTC with the following query

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this? fixing it up for hr:min would be a task, but minutes is easy.

```
declare @starttime datetime = '2016-6-20 7:30AM'
declare @endtime datetime = '2016-6-20 8:00AM'
select rtrim(datediff(minute,@starttime, @endtime)) + ' min'
```

edit, try this  query

```
;with duration_dates as 
( 
    SELECT top (100)
        dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,0,Start_Time_UTC)/ 15)*15,0) Start_Time_UTC
        ,dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,0,dateadd(minute,15,End_time_UTC))/15)*15,0) End_time_UTC 
        --,<your id column here>
    FROM EmployeeSchedules
)
SELECT
     TimeInterval 
    ,Start_Time_UTC 
    ,End_time_UTC
    ,datediff(minute, Start_Time_UTC,End_time_UTC) duration 
FROM Times 
LEFT JOIN duration_dates ON CAST(Start_Time_UTC AS Time) = TimeInterval
```

Comment: I'm running this query: SELECT TOP (100)
TimeInterval,
Start_Time_UTC,
End_time_UTC
FROM Dbo.Times
LEFT JOIN EmployeeSchedules ON CAST(Start_Time_UTC AS Time) = Dbo.Times.TimeInterval. The problem is that in my column _Start_Time_UTC there are intervals that starts at 18:15 and I want those 18:15 to be part of 18:00 Interval. Then, I want to calculate the duration between start time and TimeInterval, for instance, TimeInterval 18:00, Start Time 18:15, End_Time 18:45, Duration 15 Minutes or TimeInterval 19:00, Start Time 19:00,End_Time 19:30, Duration 30 minutes, does that make sense?

Comment: This one is working for me: SELECT TOP (100) 
     TimeInterval
    ,iif(datepart(minute,Start_Time_UTC) = 15,dateadd(minute,-15,Start_Time_UTC),Start_Time_UTC) Start_Time_UTC
 ,End_time_UTC
 ,datediff(minute,iif(datepart(minute,Start_Time_UTC) = 15,dateadd(minute,-15,Start_Time_UTC),Start_Time_UTC),End_time_UTC) duration
 

FROM Times 
LEFT JOIN EmployeeSchedules ON CAST(Start_Time_UTC AS Time) = TimeInterval, I'm just missing one little thing which is duration by interval not duration in total, duration by interval is working for < 15 or 20 minutes interval but not for >30

Comment: added new test, should work rounding down for start and up for end, I assume that's the desire.